# While controller with a counter and regex extractor for multiple users

Tags: jmeter

There is a SOAP request which gives total pages in the response and this request needs to be sent as many number of times as of the total pages, keeping page number as a variable. The counter/while controller is not working fine during the load test. The counter stops as soon as it finds a match for one customer. But my requirement is to loop through all the pages for all customers at the same time. Can anyone help?

I.Threadgroup--with 10 threads 
    A.While Controller ${__javaScript(${pagenum} < ${totalpages})} 
      1.Request 
        i.Regex extractor(totalpages) 
        ii.Counter(pagenum) 
        iii. CSV Data set config(customer)
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "The counter stops as soon as it finds a match for one customer" ?

Comment: Let's say customer1 has got 29 pages, so it has to send the requests 29 times with pagenum varying from 1 to 29.
Customer2 has got 2 pages, so it should run 2 times, Customer 3 has 16 pages so it should run 16 times and so on.

It is running fine for single user. When I run for multiple users, It will run for 2 times and the test stopsI need the customer1 request to run 29 times, customer 2 to run 2 times etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the `Test_${customer}` sampler and paste it just **before the while controller**, now you have 2 of them, remove the **counter** from both of them.

Add a [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) to the first sampler (which is out of the while controller) and add the below code into the code area:

```
int Counter = 1;
vars.put("Counter", String.valueOf(Counter));
```

Now remove the **regular expression extractor** from the second sampler (which is inside the while controller) and add **BeanShell PostProcessor** with the below code into the code area:

```
int Counter = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Counter"));
Counter = Counter + 1;
vars.put("Counter", String.valueOf(Counter));
```